# Bad float conversion on C# using VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, floating-point-conversion

I am getting a very weird behavior here with C#:

```
float num = 144771463f;
// num is 144771456.0
```

I have also tried

```
float num = Convert.ToSingle(144771463f);
// num is still 144771456.0
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: What kind of result do you want to see?

Comment: It is not weird.  The *float* type can store up to 7 significant digits.  You've got 9.  Use *double* instead, it can store up to 15 sig digs.  Use *decimal* if you don't like random number generators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're hitting inherent limtations in the `System.Single` type (`float` is a name-alias of `Single`).

According to MSDN ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx ) the `Single` type has 22 bits dedicated to the mantissa (also known as the significand), these are the bits that store the actual 'numbers' in the value (the other 10 bits store the positive/negative sign and the exponent).

22 bits means you have an effective range of `0`-`4,194,304` - whereas the number you're storing is `144,771,463`, which is 2 decimal digits beyond the (approximate) 7-digit decimal precision of `Single`. So it will only store `144,771,46X` (the value of the `X` digit won't be stored, but its magnitude will be stored in the exponent area).

You have a few options:

1. Use `System.Double` which provides for 51 bits of mantissa
2. Use `System.Decimal` which provides for 96 bits of numeric information, note that `Decimal` handles mathematical operations specially in a way that preserves more information at a cost of speed (I do not know the technical details, sorry).